# How do I create a HTML form select with sub select

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu

I have a need to create some sub selects on a form. So when you hover/click on the option a subset appears eg.

```
Lorry|
Car|Saloon
   |Coupe
   |Estate
Van|
```

I know we can create a menu dropdown but I don't know how the selection could be included in the form POST
I am not familiar with jQuery but proficient with JavaScript and PHP

If used unordered list with some css and java script I can get the effect I want but don't know how to record the value select with out using

```
    <form method="POST" action="#"> <ul>
    <li ><a href="#" >Lorry</a> </li>
    <li ><a href="#" >Car</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Saloon</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Coupe</a>
            <li><a href="#">Estate</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li ><a href="" >Van</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Basic</a>    </li>
            <li><a href="#">Luton</a> <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Low Loader</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tail lift</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Transit</a>    </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
        <input type="text" name="Vehicle" id="Vehicle" hidden>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is make another select (outside of the first one) and let it dynamically adjust to the value of the first select. You can do this by adding on eventlistener to the first select:

```
const vechicleTypeSelector = document.getElementById('vechicleTypeSelector')
vechicleTypeSelector.addEventListener('change', (event) => updateValuesOtherSelector())
```

This is one way you can solve it. I don't know if it is possible in raw HTML.

Comment: Nice idea but I am hoping to save space on the screen ( It is a little crowded )

Comment: Yes, then @JasonBruce his answer is probably better!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could save some space, then you could add the category values to your options to indicate the category.

```
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
 <form action="#">
  <select>
   <option value="0">Select car:</option>
   <optgroup label="Car" data-max-options="2">
   <option value="1">Saloon</option>
   <option value="2">Coupe</option>
   <option value="3">Estate</option>
   <optgroup label="Van" data-max-options="2">
   <option value="6">Astrovan</option>
   <option value="7">Windstar</option>
   <option value="8">Pacifica</option>
  </select>
 </form>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/L6nc9rwh/1/

Comment: Thank you @Jason Bruce.  This is a good compromise and doesn't take long to introduce